# How can I find out whether my current PowerShell console runs elevated (as administrator)

Tags: windows, powershell, uac

Is there a cmdlet or some other way to find out whether my current PowerShell console runs as administrator, i.e. elevated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if ((New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) { 
Write-Host "Elevated." 
} else { 
Write-Host "Not elevated." 
}
```

Attribution: https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/check-elevation-powershell

Comment: Yes, this code works. Thank you!

Comment: Please accept the answer clicking big tick mark and upvote it. Thank you.

Comment: Is it necessary to include "New-Object"? I have always just done it without that, like so. This will either return $true or $false : ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")